# CEFSharp browser url change

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am searching for an Event when the CEFSharp browser control changes the url.

A Long time ago (*in a galaxy far far away*) I used the webbrowser control of
M̶i̶c̶r̶o̶s̶i̶t̶h̶  Microsoft and it had Events like Navigated or Navigating, is there something similar for the CEFSharp browser control ?

Currently my code looks as follows

```
CefSharp.WinForms.WebView view;
view = new WebView();
view.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
view.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
tlpMainLayout.Controls.Add(view, 0, 0);
view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
view.Address = "http://localhost:50654/";
//view.SomeEvent += ?
```

**I am using CefSharp 1.25 and the .Net Framework 2.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version `1.25` is very old and no longer supported. You'll have to dig through the source code, starting point below:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/CefSharp1/CefSharp.Example/ExamplePresenter.cs#L104

Comment: true its old but it supports .net 2.0 ... which is also old ;)

Comment: Just making it clear that nobody maintains that branch anymore, you'll have to sort yourself out :)